# CONTAINS() function ignores special characters

Tags: visual-workflow, contains

As part of Flow logic, I have a decision element that is checking if the subject line for an email-to-case contains the string "`[Critical]`" or "`[Urgent]`", including the square brackets.

However, it seems that whether I use "`[Critical]`" or `[Critical]` (without the quotes) in the Value field, the square brackets are ignored. What is a solution to ensure the square brackets are also included in the condition.

Example scenarios:

Email subject line -> "[Critical] ABC not working" -> Condition is True

Email subject line -> "Critical, ABC not working" -> Condition is False

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula to do a CONTAINS instead and use that in your logic:

```
CONTAINS({!Get_Case_Subject_Line.Subject}, "\"[Critical]\"")
```

You'll required the backslashes before the quotes to "escape" them making sure the formula compiler reads them as text and not the start/end of a piece of text.

Then you can reference that directly in your formula by checking to see if it equals true